# Disable button until certain condition is met

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, button

I'm trying to make website which will enable button when the certain condition is met. But when I run it within simple if the condiiton is checked only at the beginning and it doesn't enable and disable on changing condition. Condition is changing inside other event listener so the condition is dynamically. The condition is met when the dicitonary consists only of true which means that input is proper

```
`var submitButton = document.getElementById("submit_button");`
```

And after some event listeners connected to inputs

```
`if(Object.values(check_dict).filter(x=>x==true).length === 6)
 {
       submitButton.disabled = false;
 }
 else
 {
       submitButton.disabled = true    ;
 }`
```

Comment: There's really not enough code here to diagnose the problem properly. You could put in `console.log('here 1')` `console.log('here 2')` type statements and see whether the path through the code was what you expected

Answer (score 0):

pretty straight forward.  add an eventlistener to the input you want to watch and then disable the submit button inside the function

```js
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('input',myFunc) 


function myFunc(){

if(event.target.value == "x")document.getElementById("submit_button").disabled = true;
else document.getElementById("submit_button").disabled = false;

 
 }
```

```html
<input id ='submit_button' type='submit'>

<input id='test'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `removeAttribute()` and `setAttribute()` to toggle the state of the submit button using a conditional.

See the snippit for a very simple example of how to toggle states using classes with `.classList` along with add/remove attribute method.

```js
const checkInput = (e) => {
  if(e.target.value.length >= args.rules.length){
    e.target.classList.remove('error')
    e.target.classList.add('success')
    submitBtn.removeAttribute('disabled')
    inputDisplay.textContent = args.success.value
  }else{
    e.target.classList.add('error')
    e.target.classList.remove('success')  
    submitBtn.setAttribute('disabled', 'true') 
    inputDisplay.textContent = args.error.value
  }
}

const args = {
  rules: {
    length: 8
  },
  success: {
    value: "Success! You may submit now!"
  },
  error: {
    value: "Input must contain 8 or more characters!"
  }
}

const fname = document.getElementById('fname')
const submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit')
const inputDisplay = document.getElementById('input-display')
inputDisplay.textContent = args.error.value
submitBtn.disabled = 'true'
fname.addEventListener('input', checkInput)
```

```css
.success {
  color: darkgreen;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.error {
  color: darkred;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<input name="firstname" id="fname" placeholder="Please enter your first name">
<button id="submit" type="button">Submit</button>
<div id="input-display"></div>
```